# Securing an ADO.net WCF data service with ASP.NET Membership

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

HI,

I am using WCF DataServices, i am trying to securing it using asp.net membership

here is my code,

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureWSBindingWithMembershipConfig" >
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecureServiceWithMembershipBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" roleProviderName="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="DataService.WcfDataService" behaviorConfiguration="SecureServiceWithMembershipBehavior">
        <endpoint address="WcfDataService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler" bindingConfiguration="SecureWSBindingWithMembershipConfig" >
          <!--<identity>
              <dns value="" />
          </identity>-->
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I am getting following error:

The operation 'ProcessRequestForMessage' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, the method must not use any other types of parameters.

Comment: Can you post your code for your messages? It seems you need to put it all inside your message object. Instead of `Method(RequestMessage request, OtherType type, string str, int value)` you should have only `Method(RequestMessage request)` and that RequestMessage type has only the parameters you need for the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, if this is almost like your code:

```
Method(RequestMessage request, OtherType value)

// Your message contract much like this.
[MessageContract]
public class RequestMessage {
     [MessageBodyMember]
     public OtherType { get; set; }
}

// And your new method will be
Method(RequestMessage request)
```